# Record inserted twice into database

Tags: database, postgresql, go

I have code in Go like below :

```
package main

import (  
  "database/sql"
  "log"

  _ "github.com/lib/pq"

)


const (
    insertLoginSQL   = `insert into Logins(id, name,password) values($1, $2, $3)`
)

func main() {  

     db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=postgres password=admin dbname=Quality sslmode=disable")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    if err := Insert(db); err != nil {
        log.Println("error with double insert", err)
    }

}

func Insert(db *sql.DB) error {
    tx, err := db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

        stmt, err := tx.Prepare(insertLoginSQL)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer stmt.Close()

        if _, err := stmt.Exec(10, "user","pwd"); err != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            return err
        }

    return tx.Commit()
}
```

When I run above code, records inserted twice in database. Can someone let me know why duplicate records inserted? Any issue with this code?

Comment: Try not calling `stmt.Close()`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably commit is done twice. First time by some of previous operations like `stmt.exec` and second time when `tx.Commit()` executed.

Comment: If i remove tx.commit() then no records inserted in database.What could be reason for duplicate records insertion?

Comment: Please take a look this article: http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/practical-persistence-sql

Especially section "Executing a statement". There is example how author created endpoint for POST with INSERT to DB. Hope that this will help you. P.S. I don't see any transactions in this example only Exec

Comment: Thanks. I will check it.

Comment: Ok, if you need some help ping me and I will try to help you! ;-)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I need one more help. In my Go routine, I have response object array ( with fields and values that mapped to struct type). Is there any way to pass this object from handler to html page  and iterate and display each variable with value ?

Comment: Thanks, I am glad to hear that! ;-)

Comment: can you help me here

Comment: In my Go routine, I have response object array ( with fields and values that mapped to struct type). Is there any way to pass this object from handler to html page and iterate and display each variable with value ?